# TJSONUnMarshal reverter on subitem in JSONObject

Tags: json, delphi, unmarshalling

I'm trying to figure out how the Reverters work for a TJSONUnMarshal object. I have a TJSONObject based on some JSON that consists of the following properties:

```
{
  "header": {
    "id": 39,
    "relation": "Test Company",
    "relationId": "00214",    
    "changeDate": "2023-02-22 15:18:30",
  },
  "lines": {
    "lines": []
  }
}
```

And a corresponding Class named TCustomer which contains a property TCustomerHeader and TCustomerLines. This is where I try to do the UnMarshal(Based on the Rest.JSONReflect uses) on:

```
procedure TCustomer.LoadFromJSonObj(objJSON: TJSONObject);
var
  objUnMarshaller: TJSONUnMarshal;
begin
  objUnMarshaller := TJSONUnMarshal.Create();
  try
    objUnMarshaller.RegisterReverter(TCustomer, 'header.changeDate',
      procedure(Data: TObject; Field: string; Arg: string)
      begin
        TCustomer(Data).FHeader.ChangeDate := EncodeDateTime(StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 1, 4)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 6, 2)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 9, 2)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 12, 2)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 15, 2)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 18, 2)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 21, 3)));
      end);

     objUnMarshaller.CreateObject(TCustomer, objJSON, self);
  finally
     objUnMarshaller.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But the CreateObject fails cause of the changeDate datetime it seems and that's why I want to use a Reverter but I'm unable to figure out how to activate it since the changeDate is within a different class(TCustomerHeader).

Is it even possible to set a Reverter to a subitem within some JSON?

When I try to do the Unmarshal on just the TCustomerHeader class, the reverter is triggered if I set the field to just 'changeDate', so I do know it works.

When I try to set the Class of the header on the Reverter, it doesn't go to my breakpoint there.

```
    procedure TCustomer.LoadFromJSonObj(objJSON: TJSONObject);
var
  objUnMarshaller: TJSONUnMarshal;
begin
  objUnMarshaller := TJSONUnMarshal.Create();
  try
    objUnMarshaller.RegisterReverter(TCustomerHeader, 'changedDate',
      procedure(Data: TObject; Field: string; Arg: string)
      begin
        TCustomerHeader(Data).ChangeDate := EncodeDateTime(StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 1, 4)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 6, 2)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 9, 2)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 12, 2)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 15, 2)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 18, 2)), StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 21, 3)));
      end);

     objUnMarshaller.CreateObject(TCustomer, objJSON, self);
  finally
     objUnMarshaller.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You can only register reverters for a direct field in the class. You should do this instead: `objUnMarshaller.RegisterReverter(TCustomerHeader, 'changeDate');`. Also your implementation of string to date conversion will fail for `2023-02-22 15:18:30`, because there's no milliseconds part, that your function is trying to convert. Anyhow, you wouldn't need any reverter if the date on input was in any of the [supported formats](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Json.Types.TJsonDateFormat), e.g. `2023-02-22T15:18:30`.

Comment: It looks like the Reverter isn't triggered when I set the Class to TCustomerHeader while the Unmarshal is done on the Class TCustomer. I presume I would have to do the Unmarshalling on the TCustomerHeader individually.

But you were right about the date, if I set the string to "changeDate": "2023-02-23T13:36:51.222Z" it does Unmarshal correctly. But this would not work for me since this is meant for a rest api where we want to show the date to the user without the timezone info.

But in a PUT request this goes wrong...

Comment: So if the user calls the GET function it should show the date like `"changeDate": "2023-02-22 15:18:30"` but during the PUT it needs to be send back as  `"changeDate": "2023-02-23T13:36:51.222Z"` which is difficult since it uses the same model with some JSONConverters..

Comment: Have you tried registering a reverter as per my previous comment? It should work. Notice that you need to register it for field name `'changeDate'`, not `'header.changeDate'`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, see my edited post at the end. I put a breakpoint on the TCustomerHeader(Data).ChangeDate line but it doesn't hit it for some reason.

Comment: You have a typo there: change**d**Date. Sample JSON contains `changeDate`.

Comment: Ah you are correct, I've changed it now and ran it again but it still doesn't stop at my breakpoint. I also tried it on a non-date property like 'relation' but even then it doesn't seem to enter the reverter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question (before edit) was why the custom JSON reverter isn't called when it was registered as `objUnMarshaller.RegisterReverter(TCustomer, 'header.changeDate', …`. In the comment I explained that you can only register reverters for direct fields of a class, which will then apply to all instances (top-level or nested) of that class in context defined by `objUnMarshaller`. You adopted the suggested change with a typo, which I pointed out in another comment. After all that you claim that it doesn't work as expected. But it works for me, however I tested it with my own definition of `TCustomer` and `TCustomerHeader` classes, because you didn't provide them in your question. Here's my code:

```
type
  TCustomerHeader = class
  private
    FID: Integer;
    FRelation: string;
    FRelationID: string;
    FChangeDate: TDateTime;
  public
    property ID: Integer read FID write FID;
    property Relation: string read FRelation write FRelation;
    property RelationID: string read FRelationID write FRelationID;
    property ChangeDate: TDateTime read FChangeDate write FCHangeDate;
  end;

  TCustomer = class
  private
    FHeader: TCustomerHeader;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Header: TCustomerHeader read FHeader;
  end;

procedure TestCase;
var
  objUnMarshaller: TJSONUnMarshal;
  objJSON: TJSONObject;
  Customer: TCustomer;
begin
  objUnMarshaller := TJSONUnMarshal.Create();
  try
    objUnMarshaller.RegisterReverter(TCustomerHeader, 'changeDate',
      procedure(Data: TObject; Field: string; Arg: string)
      begin
        TCustomerHeader(Data).ChangeDate := EncodeDateTime(
          StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 1, 4)),
          StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 6, 2)),
          StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 9, 2)),
          StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 12, 2)),
          StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 15, 2)),
          StrToInt(Copy(Arg, 18, 2)), 0);
      end);

    Customer := TCustomer.Create;
    try
      objJSON := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(CustomerJSON) as TJSONObject;
      try
        objUnMarshaller.CreateObject(TCustomer, objJSON, Customer);
      finally
        objJSON.Free;
      end;
      Writeln('header.id = ', Customer.Header.ID);
      Writeln('header.relation = ', Customer.Header.Relation);
      Writeln('header.relationId = ', Customer.Header.RelationID);
      Writeln('header.changeDate = ', DateTimeToStr(Customer.Header.ChangeDate));
    finally
      Customer.Free;
    end;
  finally
    objUnMarshaller.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In the comments under the question you mention that you want to apply custom timestamp format also in serialization to JSON. For that you would need to register converter within `TJSONMarshal` instance. But there's another option. You can declare custom JSON interceptor for a field via [`JsonReflect`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.JsonReflect.JsonReflectAttribute) attribute. The interceptor can implement custom conversion routines from/to JSON values.

```
type
  TMyDateInterceptor = class(TJSONInterceptor)
  private const
    FormatSettings: TFormatSettings = (
      DateSeparator: '-';
      TimeSeparator: ':';
      ShortDateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd';
      LongTimeFormat: 'hh:nn:ss');
  public
    function StringConverter(Data: TObject; Field: string): string; override;
    procedure StringReverter(Data: TObject; Field: string; Arg: string); override;
  end;

function TMyDateInterceptor.StringConverter(Data: TObject; Field: string): string;
var
  Context: TRTTIContext;
  Value: TDateTime;
begin
  Value := Context.GetType(Data.ClassType).GetField(Field).GetValue(Data).AsType<TDateTime>;
  Result := FormatDateTime(FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat + ' ' + FormatSettings.LongTimeFormat, Value, FormatSettings);
end;

procedure TMyDateInterceptor.StringReverter(Data: TObject; Field, Arg: string);
var
  Context: TRTTIContext;
  Value: TDateTime;
begin
  Value := StrToDateTime(Arg, FormatSettings);
  Context.GetType(Data.ClassType).GetField(Field).SetValue(Data, Value);
end;
```

This is how you apply the interceptor to a field:

```
type
  TCustomerHeader = class
  private
    FID: Integer;
    FRelation: string;
    FRelationID: string;
    [JsonReflect(ctString, rtString, TMyDateInterceptor)]
    FChangeDate: TDateTime;
  public
    property ID: Integer read FID write FID;
    property Relation: string read FRelation write FRelation;
    property RelationID: string read FRelationID write FRelationID;
    property ChangeDate: TDateTime read FChangeDate write FCHangeDate;
  end;
```

You can then use `TJSONMarshal` / `TJSONUnMarshal` with no extra converters / reverters to manipulate with JSON. Or you can forget about them both and use convenient `TJson` class methods for JSON conversion:

```
procedure TestCase;
const
  CustomerJSON =
     '{' + sLineBreak +
      '  "header": {' + sLineBreak +
      '    "id": 39,' + sLineBreak +
      '    "relation": "Test Company",' + sLineBreak +
      '    "relationId": "00214",' + sLineBreak +
      '    "changeDate": "2023-02-22 15:18:30"' + sLineBreak +
      '  }' + sLineBreak +
      '}';
var
  Customer: TCustomer;
begin
  Customer := TJson.JsonToObject<TCustomer>(CustomerJSON);
  try
    Writeln(TJson.ObjectToJsonString(Customer));
  finally
    Customer.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for this excellent example! The JsonReflect attribute seems to fix the issue with that TMyDateInterceptor class!